# React / Material UI onClick doesn't work when given two functions

Tags: reactjs, function, button, material-ui, onclick

i have this Material UI Button inside a React Component

```
interface ConfirmBorrowPopupProps{
    amount : number; 
    function: Function;

}

export function ConfirmBorrowPopup(borrowPopupProps: PropsWithChildren<ConfirmBorrowPopupProps>){
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
 

    const handlePopupClickOpen = () => {
        setOpen(true);
    };
    
    const handlePopupClose = (value: string) => {
        setOpen(false);
    };

        return(
        <Box >
            
            <VaultButton  variant="contained" fullWidth={true}
            onClick={(event) => {handlePopupClickOpen();  borrowPopupProps.function?.()}}
            >
                {borrowPopupProps.children}
            </VaultButton>
</Box>)
```

which is supposed to execute both functions handlePopupClickOpen() and props.function?.().

Where handlePopupClickOpen() is `const handlePopupClickOpen = () => { setOpen(true); };` changes the state for `const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);`

and props.function?.() is a function given to the button. The problem is when I use onClick with each function separately, they both work out perfectly as expected, but when i put them together like above, only the borrowPopupProps.function?.() function execute. Is it a problem due to how React handles state change ? I'm quite confused as i've already looked this issue on other StackOverflow posts and none of the solutions seem to be working, and i genuinely don't see any explanation on why the setOpen(true); is never called.

I have tried to put the function borrowPopupProps.function?.() inside the handlePopupClickOpen function, but still only the borrowPopupProps.function?.() execute like this : `const handlePopupClickOpen = () => { borrowPopupProps.function?.(); setOpen(true); };`

and then only call the handlePopupClickOpen inside the button `<VaultButton  variant="contained" fullWidth={true} onClick={handlePopupClickOpen} >` but it doesn't work. Does anybody know how to fix this and / or why it happens ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your two expressions ***are*** both run. You're basically inside an anonymous function defined in the template. And that function is run, like you'd expect.

You probably believe `setOpen(true)` has not been executed because it is not synchronous. The current value of `open` variable is not changed. Instead, React requests a new render with the updated value.

[From docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#ive-updated-the-state-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-value):

> This is because [state behaves like a snapshot](https://react.dev/learn/state-as-a-snapshot).
> Updating state requests another render with the new state value, but does not affect the JavaScript variable in your already-running event handler.

---

A possible fix:

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
useEffect(() => {
  open && borrowPopupProps.function?.()
}, [open])

return (
  // ...
  <VaultButton onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>
    {borrowPopupProps.children}
  </VaultButton>
  // ...
)
```

Note this runs `borrowPopupProps.function?.()` every time `open` changes to `true`. If you only want it in some scenarios, update the condition to reflect that logic.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, even adding the useEffect hook don't change the result, and i still only get borrowPopupProps.function?.() to "run" (i mean the website update visually). When checking with the useEffect hook by console logging the value of open, i see that it effectively turns true as you said, but instantly goes back to false after that. Is it because React rerender the page everytime i change the value of open ? If so, how can i keep the value persistent ?

Comment: No. From what you describe, something else turns it back to `false`, but you haven't included it in the question, which means nobody can tell you what exactly. If you need help figuring it out, I suggest creating a *runnable* [mcve] using codesandbox.io or a similar service.

Comment: Alright i managed to fix the problem for my specific issue by changing tons of things so i wouldn't have to use the function i passed as a prop in my onClick handler, but still it is very interresting to me why a function passed as a prop cause the state to reload every time. I'm really thankful for your answers tho !

Comment: @HighPoint, the component would reset `state` (back to the original `false`) if it was completely re-rendered (e.g: would be conditionally rendered and the condition would change). React also resets `state` of a virtual DOM node when its position in parent changes or when its root tag changes. To prevent this behavior you'd need to use a `key={uniqueIdentifier}`. As already stated, without a *runnable* example I can't be of more help.